# Its possible to declare an enum without migration in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I dont have any migration to add an enum in my model

```
enum status: { run: 'run', see: 'see', stay: 'stay' }, _default: :run
```

i am working with rails 7,  when i used that enum

```
class Debt < ApplicationRecord
    def payment_status
        current_status = self.payment_status['run']
```

i am getting this error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `run' for nil:NilClass
status.run
```

its possible to declare without a migration in my model?

and how can i use it?

Comment: The bare word `run` at the end of the line is a method call. You want `:run`.

Comment: @user229044 even with that fix typo it return the same error

Comment: Maybe re-read https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html. `status.run` is not a thing, that's not how you use enums.

Comment: enum is a Rails column type, it uses an underlying integer column in sql. You need to have a table column called status, which should be an integer. If you don't have this, you need a migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with migrations. This is not how you use enums:

```
current_status = status.run
```

`status` is the property that exists on your model, defined by the enum. Its value is `nil`. You're invoking `nil.run`.

If you want to access the status, you just access it:

```
current_status = status
```

`enum status` is one of the examples specifically given by the documentation, you can read about exactly how to use it here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html